# tk_app.mainloop() causes mac to crash and reboot

Tags: python, tkinter, crash

I have a simple GUI application using tkinter for the front end of a simple database. 
I have used py2app to package it into a .app and a previous version worked no problem, however with a new version launching the .app causes my mac to crash and reboot.

I even re-installed the old (and previously working) version of the app onto my mac and it causes the same crash. Running the program (running the same file that the MyApp exe in MacOS calls) from pycharm causes no error and works fine.

When it crashes I get no error message or console log (that I can find) but know that the line 'app.mainloop()' is the problem by commenting out each line individually.

The app is uses a 700MB image folder and a 20MB dictionary (the main database).

Any suggestion for where to even begin with this problem would be amazing.

The file that is called by the exe in the MacOS directory is

```
from myApp import gui
app = gui.MainScreen()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't think that `mainloop()` is your problem. Most likely it is something in your code that is being reached after `mainloop`. That said your previous version no longer works so that probably means it may not even be your code directly. Maybe a compatibility issue after an update?

Comment: I wrote a basic tkinter app 3 weeks ago and it works fine. Now, running it causes the screen to go black and log me out of my Mac. I have updated MacOS Mojave to 10.14.6 (from 10.14.5) in the meantime, so I'm very suspicious that this is behind it as my code is unchanged from 3 weeks ago.

Comment: I'm even more suspicious now. https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/11165 suggests it is Apple's issue

Comment: Excellent find. I am on macOS 10.14.6 but don't think I have anaconda installed (conda info returns command not found) but it's possible pycharm has installed it somewhere.